# UITextView prevent apple's automatic changes

Tags: ios, textview, uitextfield, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

When editing a UITextView, Apple inserts the following edits for the user automatically

1) A ". " when a user double spaces after a word.
2) An extra space deleted when a whole word is a selected and deleted. EX "My string" with "string" selected and then delete key pressed makes just "My" instead of "My "

Is there any way to prevent or detect these? Especially the second one? The first one does register in **textView shouldChangeTextInRange** but the second on doesn't, so there is no relatively simple way to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

Set UITextView correction option to "No".

[image]

Comment: Turning off Correction has no bearing on adding a period when adding two spaces or removing a space when deleting a word.